# Count ocurrences based on several conditions for two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, count, subquery, inner-join

I have two tables.

Table 1:

```
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| ID         | varchar(255)| NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| Sex        | int(20)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Age        | varchar(255)| YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Table 2:

```
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| ID        | varchar(255) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| var1      | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| var2      | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

What I want to do, is, based on a condition of three of the variables, as for example:

- Sex = 1
- Age = 3 (groups)
- var1 = "Wisconsin"

count the number of ocurrences. That is, the number of persons with that conditions.

The main problem that I´m finding is that the second table has a different amount of samples for each individual. So the number of rows in table2 is far bigger than in number1.

To make it clear:

```
Table1
+------------+-------------+------+
| ID         | Sex         | Age  |
+------------+-------------+------+
| 1          | 1           | 2    |
| 2          | 0           | 4    | 
| 3          | 0           | 3    | 
+------------+-------------+------+

Table 2
+------------+-------------+---------+
| ID         | Var1        | Var2    |
+------------+-------------+---------+
| 1.1        | "Wisconsin" | var2_1  |
| 1.2        | "Wisconsin" | var2_2  | 
| 1.3        | "Wisconsin" | var2_3  | 
+------------+-------------+---------+
```

I guess that firstly it is needed a preselection of the individuals based on var 1 for table 2, and then, I can carry on with the query for the ocurrences, but so far I didn´t manage to find a way of doing that.

Any help would be appreciated it.

Comment: What if only some of the rows in `table2` are "Wisconsin" for `id = 1`?

Comment: In this case the data is the define so each individual has always the same var1

Comment: . . Then the solution is to fix your data model.  You shouldn't be repeating the value in `table2`.

Answer (score 1):

If I follow you correctly, you can use `exists` to filter on `table2`:

```
select count(*) as cnt
from table1 t1
where t1.sex = 1 and t1.age = 3 and exists (
    select 1
    from table2 t2 
    where t2.id = t1.id and t2.var1 = 'Wisconsin'
)
```

This counts rows in the first table for which *at least one* row in the second table has Wisconsin. If, on the other hand, you want to ensure that *all rows* in the second table satisfy the condition, then an option is:

```
select count(*) as cnt
from table1 t1
inner join (
    select id
    from table2
    group by id
    having min(var1 <=> 'Wisconsin') = 1
) t2 on t2.id = t1.id
where t1.sex = 1 and t1.age = 3
```

Comment: Thx! However, I forgot to say that ID has different names in table 2 for each sample, let´s say 1.1, 1.2,1.3.. as this was an example of the real data. Could it be enough something like DISTINCT(SUBSTRING(id, 1, 2))

Comment: @Roy_Batty: `where substring_index(t2.id, '.', 1) = t1.id` in the subquery?

Answer (score 0):

You can find `distinct` person as follows:

```
select count(distinct t1.id) as cnt
  from table1 t1 join table2 t2 on t2.id = t1.id 
  where t1.sex = 1 and t1.age = 3 and t2.var1 = 'Wisconsin';
```