# Count ocurrences between two tables and several variables in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I´m having some troubles with this query.

I have two tables:

Table 1:

```
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| ID         | varchar(255)| NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| Sex        | int(20)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Income     | varchar(255)| YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Table 2:

```
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| ID        | varchar(255) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| var1      | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| var2      | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

What I want to do, is, based on a condition of three of the variables, as for example:

- Sex = 1
- Income = 3 (groups)
- var1 = "Wisconsin"

count the number of ocurrences. That is, the number of persons with that conditions.

The main problem that I´m finding is that the second table has a different amount of rows, as it has a different amount of samples for each individual, and because of that, each row in the ID column has a different name between the two tables.

To make it clear:

```
Table1
+------------+-------------+---------+
| ID         | Sex         | Income  |
+------------+-------------+---------+
| 5463D      | 1           | 2       |
| 1236Y      | 0           | 4       | 
| 7456H      | 0           | 3       | 
+------------+-------------+---------+

Table 2
+------------+-------------+---------+
| ID         | Var1        | Var2    |
+------------+-------------+---------+
| 5463D-567  | "Wisconsin" | var2_1  |
| 1236Y-856  | "Wisconsin" | var2_2  | 
| 7456H-569  | "Nevada"    | var2_3  | 
+------------+-------------+---------+
```

I think the solution can go through making a subquery for the table 2, or maybe creating a temporary table with the variables needed. But I haven´t found a way of doing so so far.

Any help would be appreciated it.

Comment: How is this different from [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65264816/count-ocurrences-based-on-several-conditions-for-two-tables)?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use:

```
select count(*)
from table1 t1
where t1.sex = 1 and t1.income = 3 and
      exists (select 1
              from table2 t2
              where t1.id = substring_index(t2.id, '-', 1) and
                    t2.var1 = 'Wisconsin'
             );
```